# fprintf memory leak

Tags: c, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments, valgrind

I am using the Instruments from XCode 4.2.1 to find some memory leaks.
I have found a very weird (at least for me) memory leak:
(The function `values_table_get_value` returns a double, and `output = stdout`)
[image]

The two questions are:
Is it a real memory leak? 
How can I clean up it? (The `fprintf` format `%.3f` is wrong for a `double`?

To show that the leak is inside the fprintf, I changed the return from the function to `5.0`:

[image]

and moving the return to a temporary variable:

[image]

and to be more precise, here is a picture of the asm code that shows that the leak is:
[image]

I did a very simple test: printing using the `sprintf` + `fprintf`, but I get the leak at sprintf:
[image]

I also tried to use the `printf` directly, and I get the leak on it.

**I am really thinking that the problem is in format.**

The final try, to show that do not have anything related with my function:
[image]

Just to check, I executed with valgrind: (`values_table_print` is the function name)
`valgrind --leak-check=full  --show-reachable=yes ./leastsquares`

[image]

My software versions:
valgrind --version: valgrind-3.7.0
gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)

Comment: Abstract it, this function returns a double and the leak is in the fprintf.

Comment: The important question here is: What is the definition of output?

Comment: In this case, output = stdout.

Comment: So, my guess is that a buffer is created first time you use stdout. This will visibly leak, but does not matter since it will anyway be closed at program exit. To verify that, you can try replacing fprintf with fputc(32, output); and check that the same faux memory leak happens

Comment: Thank for the idea kotlinski, but I the leak apparently is in the format.

Comment: It could be a memory leak in the C library, when handling that particular format.

Comment: Argh, people, learn what a memory leak is!

Comment: Surround your printf statements with autorelease pools.  Normally there's an outer autorelease pool that (eventually) catches these, but you apparently don't have one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Don't waste time debugging

**Your setup probably has a bad gcc or valgrind build or simply isn't up-to-date.**

I just tried:

```
gcc -o junk /tmp/junk.cpp && ~/src/valgrind/coregrind/valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes /tmp/junk
```

on the following snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf( "%.3f", 3.0 );
}
```

#### Configuration

- OSX 10.7.2
- valgrind-3.7.0.SVN
- gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)

  Using built-in specs.
  Target: i686-apple-darwin11
  Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2335.15~25/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2335.15~25/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
  Thread model: posix
  gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)

#### Valgrind Output

```
==58980== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==58980== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==58980== Using Valgrind-3.7.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==58980== Command: /tmp/junk
==58980== 
--58980-- /tmp/junk:
--58980-- dSYM directory is missing; consider using --dsymutil=yes
UNKNOWN task message [id 3229, to mach_task_self(), reply 0x2503]
UNKNOWN task message [id 3229, to mach_task_self(), reply 0x2503]
UNKNOWN task message [id 3414, to mach_task_self(), reply 0x2503]
--58980-- WARNING: unhandled syscall: unix:357
--58980-- You may be able to write your own handler.
--58980-- Read the file README_MISSING_SYSCALL_OR_IOCTL.
--58980-- Nevertheless we consider this a bug.  Please report
--58980-- it at http://valgrind.org/support/bug_reports.html.
3.000==58980== 
==58980== HEAP SUMMARY:
==58980==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==58980==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==58980== 
==58980== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==58980== 
==58980== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==58980== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In fact, I am using the same valgrind, gcc and max os x version as you. But I will accept your answer, as you did a nice test.